# How do you achieve this kind of HTML escaping/encoding automaticly

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, esri

I am working on a custom plugin for esri web-app builder and I noticed two things in their dojo widget that I cannot really understand.

1. there is a cahce property that has a lot of function under it and also this kind fo property "url:widgets/PrintAndShare/templates/Print.html" which is legal by JS, but why using that instead of the standard dojo/text!.template, I see that the template itself is still loaded ( but ignored) - so the question is -how exactly that cached property works.
2. the main question is - these properties have html encoded in very specific way for example

`<div class="gis_PrintDijit">`

encoded like this

```
\x3cdiv class\x3d"gis_PrintDijit"\x3e\r\n
```

how do I achieve this kind of encoding ? with online tools or even better with some automation, for now I just use manual char replacing but it is really not efficient.

Thanks you all

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if there is a better way.

A simple workaround can be to use encodeURIComponent and then a replace:

```
var t = "<div>test ok: 100%</div>";
console.log(encodeURIComponent(t).replace(/%/g,"\\x"));
```

Comment: this is possibly a solution but I wrote that I am looking for the tool that does the process.

Comment: dont think you will find a such for javascript. its standards uses URI encoding as it operates with a browser.. it is however readable in 'eval' etc, since hex is valid encoding still. You may want to look for tools which obfuscates code. Thats mostly where youll find hex encoding - but theyre commonly operating with a php backend or similar.